# How to read file name from Postman request

Tags: postman

I am posting file name in PostMan using Form-Data and in the Pre-Request script, I want to read FileName. How to access the selected file name?

In Postman console I find request data and file property like this

> Request Body -> File -> path: "C:\myfile.txt"

but can't read it using code

```
console.log(request.File)
```

The code returns undefined.

Comment: What does the request body look like? If it's the first entry in the form data, you could use something like `console.log(pm.request.body.formdata.members[0].src)`.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be available inside the request.data.

So probably you can check like this.

console.log(request.data.File);

```
 {
  "id": "938ef57c-b7aa-45d9-bd9e-645de96f0469",
  "headers": {},
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "data": {
    "path": "hello"
  }
}
```